# Isolated points of fibers of regular morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X,Y$ be affine varieties and $\varphi:X\to Y$ be regular morphism. 
I want to prove that isolated points of fibers of $\varphi$ form open subset in $X$. Can you give me advice how to do it?

Comment: Just to check, does "variety" include "irreducible"?

Comment: @Relapsarian in general case no. But if it's not true only for reducible then i want to know what about irreducible case.

Comment: Are you sure that the assertion you want to prove is true? I think it might be necessary to require that $\varphi$ is of finite type. In this case, the desired statement is part of the yoga surrounding Zariski's main theorem - e.g., see Görtz/Wedhorn, Algebraic Geometry I, Corollary 12.79

Comment: @c_c_chaos These are varieties, so certainly $\varphi$ is finite type.

Comment: @Hoot, i'm sorry but i'm not suppose that $\varphi$ is of finite type.
Why if i say 'variety' it's means that morphism are of finite type?

Comment: $k \subset A \subset B$ and $B$ f.g. over $k$ implies f.g. over $A$. And everything is noetherian so you have all the quasicompactness you could ever want.

Comment: What is $A,B$? If you mean $B=k[X],A=k[Y]$ that it's not true for general morphism.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: What @Hoot wrote in his [last comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1343307/isolated-points-of-fibers-of-regular-morphism?noredirect=1#comment2734756_1343307) is a basic fact from commutative algebra and defintely true - see, e.g., [Lemma 10.6.2(3) in the Stacks Project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00F4). Regarding his earlier comment, he is almost certainly correct as well (indeed, I overlooked this): While there is a variety of definitions for 'variety', the affine coordinate ring of an affine variety is a finitely generated algebra over the ground field/ring no matter...

Comment: ... what definition you use (at least speaking of all the definitions I have ever seen).

Comment: Of course coordinate ring is finitely generated algebra.
But for example projection parallel of $V(xy-1)$ on $x$-axis is not finite morphism. So if we have morphism $\varphi:X\to Y$ than induced morphism of algebras is injective iff image of $\phi$ is dense.It seems there've been a misunderstanding between us.

Comment: Finite type and finite are not the same! Blame Grothendieck.